# Rubymine thinks (incorrectly) that project is already on GitHub

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, rubymine

Here is the setup: New project in RubyMine. Ran "Share Project on GitHub". It creates the repo. It *attempts* to send the project, but fails because my application firewall wanted confirmation of the new connection. I permitted it, but not before RubyMine got the error and cancelled.

Problem: Now I can not sync the project to GitHub from RubyMine. I've attempted to delete the repo from GitHub and re-run "Share Project on GitHub" but RubyMine always gives me the error "Project already exists on GitHub"...even when the repo is no longer there.

Is there a way to make RubyMine forget about this GitHub share and start fresh?

Comment: I am having the same issue on phpstorm. Did you find a solution?

Comment: I too am having this problem - with WebStorm.

Answer (score 1):

1. Go to your project physical location and find .git folder(hidden, right click open in new window, if you have problems on mac). You might need figure out how to show hidden folders/files on your OS.
2. Find file "config"
3. Delete section(s) [remote "name"]
4. Try to share again
5. Enjoy )